# How is $\sin x$ considered a function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Yeah, it's a simple question, I forgot the exact reasoning behind it.
also would a one-to-one function be considered a function (obviously yes)? If it is then how come $\sin x$ is a function.

I'm very sure I'm getting confused with one to one function and multiple $y$ value vs 1 single $x$ value.

Comment: Welcome to the Math StackExchange.  Many functions are not one-to-one including $y=x^2$

Comment: An easy way to check if something is a function is with the Vertical Line Test. If you draw a vertical line at any point on the graph, and the line hits 2 or more points, it's not a function. A function is one-to-one if it passes the Horizontal Line Test. If you draw a horizontal line anywhere on the function, it should hit the function at one point at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(x)$ is a function, because -by definition- any value for $x$ produces only one value. A function can be one-to-one, but doesn't have to.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(x)$ is a function because for any value of $x$, $\sin(x)$ gives one single value. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 2):

Informally, a **function** is any rule which takes an  *input* and assigns a **unique** output.

Example: Let $x$ be the date, $f(x)$ be  the number of apples you ate that day. $f(x)$ is a function, because you cant eat both $2$ apples and $3$ apples, for example.

Non-example: Let $x$ be the date, $f(x)$ a fruit you ate that day. Then if you had both an apple and an orange, $f(x)$ could be either one. It's ambiguous. This is fine as a 'relation' but it's not good enough to be a function.

Sin(x) takes as input a real number (or angle) and outputs the unique $sine$ of that number.

A function is **one-to-one** if the rule outputs a different output for every input.

Example: Let $x$ be the current date. If since you've been born you've eaten one additional apple than the previous day, i.e. $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ then you've eaten different numbers of apples on each day. So $f(x)$ is a function (as above) and it is also one-to-one.

Sin(x) is **not** one-to one, because $\sin(0^o)=\sin(180^o)$, for example.